# expo text to speech voice information

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, text-to-speech

I am wondering, how can i identify if the values i get from `Speech.getAvailableVoicesAsync()` is for women or a man.
There is simple no information available except for data that the user simple wont be able to know what is mean.

I was thinking of simple making the user chose which voice to play. but its simple to hard to present anything that i get from `Speech.getAvailableVoicesAsync()`.

Is there any way i could make it presentable. simple like `Man(en-US)` something like that.

I get something like this

```
{"identifier": "ur-PK-language", "language": "ur-PK", "name": "ur-PK-language", "quality": "Enhanced"}
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the available voices are platform specific, and most platforms do not provide gender information for the voice, except for the name (which gives a rough idea on iOS, but not in android) - https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/2833 should help for iOS.

To implement this,

Option 1: Provide a list of available voices, and play a default text message on selection.

Option 2: Provide a limited subset of voices known to you, presenting a mapped result of Speech.getAvailableVoicesAsync() with your own property for "gender": "...".